How do I upload an Excel sheet and show its data on the page?
models.py (database schemas):
from app import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

class StudentData(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    student_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    subject_type = db.Column(db.String(50))
    subject_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    instructor = db.Column(db.String(100))
    extra_column1 = db.Column(db.String(100))
    extra_column2 = db.Column(db.String(100))

class Passkey(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    passkey = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

Excel sheet uploading route:
@app.route("/upload_excel", methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def upload_excel():
    if current_user.role != 'admin':
        flash('Access denied. You must be an admin to upload data.', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('admin_panel'))
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('admin_panel'))
    if file and file.filename.endswith(('.xlsx', '.xls')):
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(file)
            print(df.columns)
            for _, row in df.iterrows():
                print(row)
                student_data = StudentData(
                    student_name=row['Names'] if pd.notna(row['Names']) else '',
                    subject=row['Subject'],
                    subject_type=row['Type'],
                    subject_name=row['Subject Name'],
                    instructor=row['Instructor'],
                    extra_column1=row.get('Extra Column 1', ''),
                    extra_column2=row.get('Extra Column 2', '')
                )
                db.session.add(student_data)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Excel data uploaded successfully', 'success')
        except Exception as e:
            flash(f'Error uploading file: {str(e)}', 'danger')
    else:
        flash('Invalid file type. Please upload an Excel file.', 'danger')
    return redirect(url_for('admin_panel'))

student_dashboard.html:
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<style>
    .dashboard-container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 2rem auto;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        color: #333;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    .table-container {
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
        color: #333;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 8px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 1rem;
        text-align: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }
    th {
        background-color: #4a90e2;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
    }
    tr:hover {
        background-color: #e8f4ff;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .dashboard-container {
            padding: 1rem;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 0.75rem;
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="dashboard-container">
    <h1>Student Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="table-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Subject Name</th>
                    <th>Instructor</th>
                    <th>Extra Column 1</th>
                    <th>Extra Column 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for data in student_data %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ data.student_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.subject }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.subject_type }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.subject_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.instructor }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.extra_column1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.extra_column2 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

How do I upload an Excel sheet and show its data on the page?

If you use pandas to read_excel(), you can also use to_html to create the page .
